# C equivalent to Arrays.sort from Java - qsort? (How do i find the nature of its implementation)

Tags: java, c, sorting

I'm fairly new to the C programming language but I know that it is not standardized in the same way as Java.

When performing a comparisson of the runtime of a algorithm, to keep the analysis fair, I need to call a method similar to Java's Array.sort(int []).

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

Seems to be my best bet but I was wondering how I could find out the backend implementation for the version of C that I'm compiling to.

How can I find out which implementation I am using? Does this depend on the Compiler or the includes? I am running I run Ubuntu and use the gcc compiler, all of my tools are obtained through the synaptic package manager or are installed by default.

I hope this question makes sense!

Kind regards,

Gavin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

qsort is part of the C stadard library, so a look at the libc code might help: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#XAzRy8oK4zA/libc/stdlib/qsort.c&q=qsort

Hope this helps,
Vlad

Comment: Fantastic, this is what I was looking for. Knowing the implementation of qsort is taken from Engineering a Sort Function allows me to compare my algorithms with all of the knowledge required.

Answer (score 6):

Run

```
man qsort
```

It gives the description of what qsort is doing. When you need to find out the information about a C function XXX, try to do `man XXX` first. Then, if there's not enough info, search for XXX on Google.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The man pages were not installed by default on my machine.

In synaptic search for manpages-dev to find the package required.

In my muddy question what I was actually seeking was the implementation of quicksort used as this can vary. Pivot choice for example can be implemented in different ways and I don't know enough to be certain the Java and C implementations would be the same.

I will certainly use this feature, thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm fairly new to the C programming
>   language but I know that it is not
>   standardized in the same way as Java.

On the contrary, C is heavily standardised. There has been an ANSI/ISO standard for C since 1989.

Comment: If you've looked at the Java spec and the C spec, you'll see the difference.  Java's spec is HEAVY by comparison -- not that the C spec is light reading.  C spec has a lot of things that are implementation defined.  Java has very few.

Answer (score 1):

Paul Hsieh present a very fast quicksort in a  [sorting comparation](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/sort.html)

[Numerical Recipes in C](http://www.fizyka.umk.pl/nrbook/bookcpdf.html) has a excelent [quicksort](http://www.fizyka.umk.pl/nrbook/c8-2.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

`qsort` is a C standard library function.

Answer (score 0):

What implementation you get depends on the libc you use. But you don't have to care about this too much, they all should behave the same.